# Wrong keyboard layouts

Tags: kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout, fcitx

I want to be able to switch my keyboard layout between German and English (UK).
As default I set it system-wide to English (UK, extended WinKeys), using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

So far it is working. Now to be able to switch, I go to KDE's keyboard settings and set my two desired layouts: the UK one and the German one (dead acute).

I am now able to switch between the two of them using the icon in the systray. The weird thing is, I don't actually get what I am selecting: When I set it to English, it actually results in a German layout. When I set it to German, I am typing Japanese katakana (カタカナ).

In the past I used fcitx to type Japanese, so maybe there is some configuration messed up. I did a complete reinstall of the OS yesterday (using Kubuntu 16.04 now),  however I kept my home directory with all the configuration files. I did not reinstall fcitx but the problem is still there. I deleted .config/fctix but it did not change anything.

I guess there is still something messed up with the config files in my home (since everything else was wiped by reinstall) but I have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I had a `.Xmodmap` file in my home directory which I created years ago. Its purpos was to remap only a single key but the default mappings for the other keys where included as well. Obviously this does not work when switching layouts.

For now I simply removed this file and now everything behaves as expected.